# How to delete everything but streets and traffic lights in JOSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

Hello I am trying to prepare a map from openstreet map (.osm) following [this tutorial](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tutorials/Import_from_OpenStreetMap)

Using [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/)

Now in my map **I need a really sparse representation of the whole map (only streets and traffic lights)**

Is there an efficient way to do so?
I am happy about hints too.

Comment: Depending on the size of your area, use an Overpass API query to fetch streets and traffic lights only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis)

*a command line Java application for processing OSM data. The tool consists of pluggable components that can be chained to perform a larger operation. For example, it has components for reading/writing databases and files, deriving/applying changes to data sources, and sorting data, (etc.). It has been written to easily add new features without re-writing common tasks such as file and database handling.*

**Note:** Follow the link for install instructions and tutorials.